# Windows phone silverlight one theme

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone

I write wp 8.1 silverlight application. How to do the same display on both phone's themes (light/dark)?  I would not want to overwrite the styles of each element. Maybe there's another way?

Comment: Not sure what you're actually asking. If you're not overwriting existing styles or anything, the light/dark themes should already be taken care of for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the requested theme for the application and don't change it throughout the app. So when user changes phone's themes it will not effect your app.